# Tangent Line of a series of points

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to find the tangent line of a series of points.

```
x     | 5.0 | 5.2 | 5.4 | 5.6 | 5.8
f(x)  | 9.2 | 8.8 | 8.3 | 7.7 | 7.0
```

I have determined that there is a local maximum to the function at 4.3, and the f'(5.2) to be -2.25. I am trying to find the tangent line of a parabola with all those points. The tangent line is the point at 5.2.

Comment: You have determined $f'(5.2) = -2.25$? How did you do this? Is there more that you know about this function that you have not shared?

Comment: I took the average rates of change of the surrounding numbers and averaged them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line with gradient $-2.25$ through the point $(5.2,8.8)$ satisfies $$y-8.8=-2.25(x-5.2).$$

Multiply out and then move the $-8.8$ to the right hand side if you want a more conventional form.

Comment: Good job! I give you my thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the second differences from the table, you could notice that they are constant. So, the data are exactly along a parabola. Since the points are exactly along the curve, write $$y=a +b x+c x^2$$ pick three points and solve for $a,b,c$. So, you have the equation of the curve and the problem becomes quite simple.

By the way, the maximum is not at $x=4.5$ but $x=4.3$.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The general form for the equation of a parabolic function is $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$. You have 5 points that you can plug in values of $x$ and $f(x)$ into this equation for. That gives you a system of 5 linear equations in the three unknowns $a, b, c$. Solve the system.

If it doesn't solve, then some of the information given is incorrect.